# Передача UTM через RewriteRule в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, get, rewrite

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить задачу.

PHP не подхватывает параметры GET в во всех вложеных страницах. Например: `/backpack_0001.html?utm_source=yandex&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=camp_1&utm_content=cont_2&utm_term=term_1`

На главной все ок. По прямой ссылке
`index.php?module=product&alias=backpack_0001&utm_source=yandex&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=camp_1&utm_content=cont_2&utm_term=term_1`
все ок.

В htaccess такой код обработки:
`RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+).html$ index.php?module=product&alias=$1 [NC,L]`

Похоже, что нужно дополнительно обработать GET параметры, но такой код не помогает:
`RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+).html?(.*)$ index.php?module=product&alias=$1&$2 [NC,L]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте флаг `QSA` в перенаправлении `RewriteRule` чтобы добавить get переменные из url в результирующую строку.

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+).html$ index.php?module=product&alias=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```